# exception handling with PHP and facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I have the following code:

```
$fql = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM user where uid=me()";
$sparam = array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => $fql, 'callback' => '', 'access_token' => $fbtoken);
try{
    $sfqlResult = $facebook -> api($sparam);
}
catch(CurlException $e) {
    echo 'There is issue with Token';
}
```

suppose if my access token is wrong I want to catch the exception, but its not catching the exception and showing traditional error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 190: Invalid OAuth access token. thrown in

any help in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [FacebookApiException Class](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/#FacebookApiException) to catch the exceptions.

Example-

```
try {
  $sfqlResult = $facebook -> api($sparam);
} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
  $e_type = $e->getType();
  $result = $e->getResult();
  error_log('Got an ' . $e_type . ' while posting');
  error_log(json_encode($result));
}
```

But according to me, there's token related issue, the exception will not be thrown but the error result will be returned in `$sfqlResult`; and you can check the object `$sfqlResult->error;`

```
if(!isset($sfqlResult['error']))
{
    // no error
}
else
{
    echo "Facebook error: ".$sfqlResult['error']->message;
}
```

Comment: If its access token related issue, the exception will not be throw acc to me. You'll get the error response in `$sfqlResult`

Comment: it throws Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 190: Invalid OAuth access token. thrown in

Comment: I think you should concentrate on the error first. The code that I've mentioned mostly take cares of everything. Are you generating the token correctly with the correct app id and app secret?

Comment: I know, but just conisdering a case if token is wrong what my users will see